# Set store cookie not working in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

I'm trying to make my first Magento 2 module so I'm new to this...

Basically what I'm trying to achieve now is:
check if a store view was set in a cookie before
  if yes: do nothing.
  if not: set English store view.
this is my code:

```
<?php

namespace HeziDebby\GeoIpRedirect\Plugin;


use HeziDebby\GeoIpRedirect\Model\GeoIpRequest;
use Magento\Framework\App\FrontControllerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Store\Api\StoreCookieManagerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\Plugin\StoreCookie;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreFactory;

class GeoIpRedirectPlugin
{

    /**
     * @var StoreFactory
     */
    private $storeFactory;
    /**
     * @var StoreCookieManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeCookieManager;
    /**
     * @var GeoIpRequest
     */
    private $geoIpRequest;
    /**
     * @var StoreCookie
     */
    private $storeCookie;

    public function __construct(
        StoreFactory $storeFactory,
        StoreCookieManagerInterface $storeCookieManager,
        GeoIpRequest $geoIpRequest
    )
    {
        $this->storeFactory = $storeFactory;
        $this->storeCookieManager = $storeCookieManager;
        $this->geoIpRequest = $geoIpRequest;
    }

    public function beforeDispatch(
        FrontControllerInterface $subject,
        RequestInterface $request
    ){

        if(!$this->storeCookieManager->getStoreCodeFromCookie()){
            $store = $this->storeFactory->create();

            $store->load('EN','country_code');

            $this->storeCookieManager->setStoreCookie($store);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

There are 2 things which I do not understand:

1) I'm debugging with Xdebug and I have set a breakpoint on the condition line, the weird thing is that in one page load, the debugging stops on this breakpoint more then once, why is that happening?
**edit: it happens because of other non related requests to frontcontroller

2) The cookie is not being set after this line

> $this->storeCookieManager->setStoreCookie($store);

And in the next time the debugger stops on the condition, the cookie is set to the default store view(it actually loads the default store view the therefore the cookie is 'default).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I recently struggled with this same dilemma - I went through 3 iterations of different approaches and finally found one that seems to be working:

- Create an [interceptor (plugin)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) on the `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver::getCurrentStoreId()` method
- Utilize the `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher` to switch to the desired store

### Module Files

`etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver">
        <plugin name="my_custom_store_resolver_current_store_id" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\StoreResolverPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

`etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\StoreResolverPlugin">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="cache" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config</argument>
            <argument name="runMode" xsi:type="init_parameter">Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE</argument>
            <argument name="scopeCode" xsi:type="init_parameter">Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

`Plugin/Model/StoreResolverPlugin` (the magic)

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model;

/**
 * Dependencies
 */
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher;

/**
 * Store Resolver Plugin
 */
class StoreResolverPlugin extends \Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface
     */
    private $serializer;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface
     */
    protected $_targetStore;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher
     */
    protected $_storeSwitcher;

    /**
     * Get Target store
     * 
     * @return \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface
     */
    protected function getTargetStore()
    {
        if (!$this->_targetStore) {
            list($stores, $defaultStoreId) = $this->getStoresData();
            $default = $this->getDefaultStoreById($defaultStoreId);

            try {
                $this->_targetStore = $this->getRequestedStoreByCode('english');
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                $this->_targetStore = $default;
            }

            // Switch stores
            $this->getStoreSwitcher()->switch($default, $this->_targetStore, $this->_targetStore->getUrl());
        }

        return $this->_targetStore;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function aroundGetCurrentStoreId(\Magento\Store\Api\StoreResolverInterface $resolver, callable $proceed)
    {
        list($stores, $defaultStoreId) = $this->getStoresData();

        $storeCode = $this->request->getParam(self::PARAM_NAME, $this->storeCookieManager->getStoreCodeFromCookie());
        if (is_array($storeCode)) {
            if (!isset($storeCode['_data']['code'])) {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException(__('Invalid store parameter.'));
            }
            $storeCode = $storeCode['_data']['code'];
        }
        if ($storeCode) {
            try {
                $store = $this->getRequestedStoreByCode($storeCode);
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                $store = $this->getTargetStore();
            }

            if (!in_array($store->getId(), $stores)) {
                $store = $this->getTargetStore();
            }
        } else {
            $store = $this->getTargetStore();
        }
        return $store->getId();
    }

    /**
     * Get serializer
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface
     * @deprecated 100.2.0
     */
    private function getSerializer()
    {
        if ($this->serializer === null) {
            $this->serializer = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get(SerializerInterface::class);
        }
        return $this->serializer;
    }

    /**
     * Get store switcher
     *
     * @return \Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher
     */
    private function getStoreSwitcher()
    {
        if ($this->_storeSwitcher === null) {
            $this->_storeSwitcher = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get(StoreSwitcher::class);
        }
        return $this->_storeSwitcher;
    }
}
```

### Notes

- The plugin is completely overriding the `getCurrentStoreId()` method. This is only executed on the `frontend` scope as it is only defined in `etc/frontend/di.xml`. The "magic" happens in the `getTargetStore()` method. You can load stores via the store repository as I did here, or you can choose to load them another way if you want to include more dependencies.

  - The main difference with the overridden `getCurrentStoreId()` method is the replacement of the `getDefaultStoreById()` calls with `getTargetStore()`.
- It seems that the only reason this works is because the store switch is only executed once:

  - The first time the script is run, `$this->_targetStore` is not yet defined and the switch is executed.
- If you would like to redirect your users to another store URL, I believe the place to do that would be right after the `$this->getStoreSwitcher()->switch()` call.
- My implementation encloses the contents of `aroundGetCurrentStoreId()` in an `if` statement that check if my module is enabled. If not, I call `$proceed()`.

I would definitely love to hear whether or not this works for your case and if you have any other thoughts or ideas to consider.